# Different user names in different applications

Tags: claims-based-identity, claims

Suppose there is a user named 'User', and he logs into a common login website with this username. He might be 'User1' in one application, and 'User2' in some other application. What do we call this feature? what is the technical term related to it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a already defined term for this, but I would be inclined to call it application-specific claim binding, where each application can bind the same claims data from the login website to a different identifying name in the application.